# how to map from a ViewModel to Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

I have a model and ViewModel like this

```
public class Estate : BaseEntity
{       
    public virtual BaseInformation floorType { get; set; }     
}

public class BaseInformation:BaseEntity 
{ 
    public string Name { get; set; }     
    public virtual BaseInformationHeader Master { get; set; }
}

public class EstateViewModel : BaseEntityViewModel
{       
    public  long floorType { get; set; }     
}
```

And the code in controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public long save(EstateViewModel estateViewModel)
{
    Estate entity = new Estate();
    BaseInformation bi = new BaseInformation();
    bi.id = 1;
    entity.floorType = bi;
    EstateViewModel ev = new EstateViewModel(); 
    Mapper.CreateMap<EstateViewModel, Estate>();
    var model = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<EstateViewModel,Estate>(estateViewModel);

    return estateRepository.save(entity);
}
```

When the action is executed AutoMapper throws the following exception:

> An exception of type 'AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException' occurred
>   in AutoMapper.dll but was not handled in user code

What is causing this to happen?

Answer (score 2):

my problem solution found here : 
http://cpratt.co/using-automapper-creating-mappings/
and the code is like this:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<PersonDTO, Person>()
.ForMember(dest => dest.Address,
           opts => opts.MapFrom(
               src => new Address
               {
                   Street = src.Street,
                   City = src.City,
                   State = src.State,
                   ZipCode = src.ZipCode
               }));
```

Comment: Glad you figured this out :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the inner exception - it gives you a good description of the problem. I would also consider setting up all of the CreateMap calls in a static method somewhere else that is called on app start:

```
public class AutoMapperConfiguration
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
         Mapper.CreateMap<EstateViewModel, Estate>();          
    }
}
```

And then in Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure();
}
```

[Update] - to map properties to other properties with different names:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ViewModel, Model>()
                  .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, o => o.MapFrom(src => src.DestinationProp));
```

The problem you have is that the source property is a `long` while the destination is a complex type - you can't map from the source to the destination as they are not the same type.

[Update 2]

If BaseInformation.Id is a long then you shoiuld be able to do this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ViewModel, Model>()
                  .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, o => o.MapFrom(src => src.floorType ));
```

You're model isn't very clear though.

Comment: the inner exception is : Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types:
Int64 -> BaseInformation
System.Int64 -> BonchaghWebApplication.Models.Core.BaseInformation

Destination path:
Estate.floorType.floorType

Source value:
1

Comment: There is nothing for floorType  to map to - what is in BaseInformation ? You will need to show the mapper how to handle this - show me what is in that class and I will have a ganders

Comment: this is BaseInformation : public class BaseInformation:BaseEntity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual BaseInformationHeader Master { get; set; }
    }

Comment: What do you want floorType  to map to? there is nothing in the target class? Are you new to C#? this would work in dynamic languages but C# is much stricter - also your naming style hints at a background in JS ;)

Comment: i want to map baseInformation id filed to floortype in viewModel

Comment: I updated my answer for you - if you're still struggling we can work it out in a gist tomorrow for you

Comment: yes , baseInformation.id in long , i do the mapping that you said and see this error:An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in AutoMapper.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Expression 'dest => Convert(dest.floorType.id)' must resolve to top-level member and not any child object's properties. Use a custom resolver on the child type or the AfterMap option instead.

Comment: my problem doesn't fix , i do the things you said but it's not working